# Assembly Addressing Modes

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32, addressing-mode

Can someone please explain what the difference between the following two are? I'm finding it a little difficult to understand the concepts behind addressing modes

```
mov ax, [bx + di + 10]
mov ax, [bx + di] + 10
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You labelled this MASM32 but neither instruction is legitimate for x86. Unless you are doing 16 bit programming, in which case you should make that clear.

```
mov ax, [bx+di+10]
```

Is not legal in x86 because it uses 16 bit addressing. The following is allowed, however:

```
mov ax, [ebx+edi+10]
```

Which means take the value of ebx, add it to the value of edi, and add 10 to that value. Then treat the final value as a pointer. Take the `word` (2 bytes) pointed to by that address and assign the value to ax.

```
mov ax, [bx+di]+10
```

Is not legal similarly (16 bit addressing). If you were to do:

```
mov ax, [ebx+edi]+10
```

That is also not allowed since `mov` does not allow an extra input after `[ebx+edi]`

Answer (score 3):

**There is no difference!**

You can check with debugger...

```
mov ax, [bx + di + 10]
mov ax, [bx + di] + 10
```

Compiler will compile boath instructions to: **8B443B0A**

So, ax should load the 16 bit value from address: **bx + di + 10**

Answer (score -4):

Suppose bx=10 , di = 10.

In case 1,

`mov ax, [30]`

The value at memory location 30 will be copied to AX register

In case 2,

`mov ax, [20]+10`

The value at memory location 20, lets say X, add 10h to it `X+10h`, will be copied to AX register.

Comment: Are you *sure* the `MOV` instruction can do addition?

Comment: Thanks! So, for the second one, the 10 is added to the *value* of `[bi+di]`? And for the first, the location from which the value is copied is offset by +10? Ss this correct?

Comment: Also, what does `mov ax, disp[bx][di]` mean?

Comment: @alan - It all means the same, add two registers and an offset (disp) to get an address. Then load the value from that address.

Comment: Don't think the answer is that bad that it needs to be modded down. His example makes it more visually insightful +1.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, it's probably downvoted because 'case 2' is not a legitimate assembler instruction.